# ¿Cómo quitar el mensaje de "la aplicación no está optimizada para la última versión de Android"?

Tags: android, bug

He estado traduciendo una aplicación Android pero he tenido problemas con las versiones de Android más recientes. Tengo el código fuente de la APK al parecer lo que hace ese error es la superposición.

[image: Error]

La aplicación se puede usar pero por ejemplo no deja escribir en el teclado, como que se congela. Si me pudieran dar orientación para arreglarlo lo agradecería. Uso **apktool** para descompilar **APKs**.

Comment: Eso no parece un error, más bien una advertencia. Más allá de eso, usa títulos específicos por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Este error ocurre comúnmente en apps como Facebook, u apps de sistema, si el mensaje indica:

> Es posible las interacciones táctiles tengan retraso o no se
> reconozcan.

Lo que necesitas, simplemente, es **asegurar que la app tenga la última actualización**, incluso probablemente necesitarías reiniciar tu dispositivo.

---

Si la app que marca este error es una que creaste, debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente:

- Asegura que el [minSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element?hl=es-419#min) definido en tu `build.gradle`, es menor al de tu dispositivo.
- En caso de tener definido en tu `build.gradle` el valor [maxSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element?hl=es-419#max), asegura que este sea mayor al de tu dispositivo.

Comment: es una app que yo estoy editando y poniendola en español pero ese erro siempre lo a tenido con android 12, 13, 14 versiones anteriores de android 12 no genera ese error

Comment: Si, agregar tu build,.gradle y tu AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: puedes adjuntar un tutorial?

Comment: bro lo necesito

Comment: agrega tu build,.gradle y tu AndroidManifest.xml a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/fdkl551vtdcvi1s/Magician-Full-espbyMasrsYT.apk/file te dejo la apk bro

Comment: porfa ayuda bro